# Edição em Listas Ligadas

Tags: c, c++, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho um protejo para a Universidade para uma cadeira de programação. Um dos objectivos é a avaliação de projectos inseridos (a parte de inserção já a tenho a funcionar), o meu problema é que **quando avalio**, não sei como mas **ele elimina a lista**. Abaixo a minha função para inserir as avaliações:

```
No * avaliarProjetos(No * head){

    int projeto;

    cout<<"Introduza o codigo do projeto\n";

    cin >> projeto;

    while (head != NULL)
    {

        if (head->codigo == projeto){

             int avaliacao;

             cout<<"Introduza a avaliacao do projeto \n";

             cin >> avaliacao;

             head->avaliacao = avaliacao;

        }

            head = head->prox;

    }

    return head;

}
```

Admita a seguinte estrutura:

```
typedef struct dados {

    int codigo;

    string titulo;

    string instituicao;

    string investigador;

    int meses;

    string palavraschave[5];

    float financiamento;

    float subsidio;

    int avaliacao;

    float mediaAvaliacoes;

    struct dados *prox; //Apontador para o próximo

}No;
```

Agradeço desde já a sua ajuda.

Comment: Aparentemente não há problemas no código apresentado. O problema deve estar na chamada à função. Como você esta chamando esta função?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você retorna o ponteiro à lista que recebeu -e ele está apontando para o final da lista ao término da execução. Esse ponteiro para o final da lista é efetivamente uma lista vazia (já que aponta para NULL):

```
No * avaliarProjetos(No * head){
    ...

    while (head != NULL)
    {...
            head = head->prox;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Então, nessa função não há erro - mas como o Vinícius apontou no comentário, você provavelmente está fazendo a chamada a ela com algo do tipo:

No *minhaLista;
   ...
   minhaLista = inserirProjetos();
   ...
   minha_lista = avaliarProjetos(minha_lista);

E ao fazer a atribuição com o valor retornado por "avaliarProjetos" você está deixando `minhaLista` com NULL.

A função `avaliarProjetos` modifica os registros "inplace" - você não vai retornar uma nova lista - então ela pode ter o tipo de retorno `void` - e você faz simplesmente `avaliarProjetos(minha_lista);` e nunca `minha_lista = avaliarProjetos(minha_lista)`  (que substitui o valor anterior da variável).